# mySQL: convert from "yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss.sssZ" to "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss"

Tags: mysql

I want to convert my data from "yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ss.sssZ" to "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss" with mySQL.

I tried with convert_tz:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2014-09-29T14:00:00.99Z','+00:00','+00:00');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz('2014-09-29T14:00:00.99Z','+00:00','+00:00') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-09-29 14:00:00                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

and with cast:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(CAST('2014-09-29T14:00:00.99Z' 
       AS datetime),'+00:00','+00:00');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ(CAST('2014-09-29T14:00:00.99Z' AS datetime),'+00:00','+00:00') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-09-29 14:00:00                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But each time I get a warning:

```
mysql> show warnings;
Level   | Code | Message
Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2014-09-29T14:00:00.99Z'
```

How can I get `2014-09-29 14:00:00` but without warning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it !

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2015-08-07T09:27:54Z','%Y-%m-%dT%TZ');
+----------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('2015-08-07T09:27:54Z','%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-08-07 09:27:54                                |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-09-29T14:00:00.99Z', '%Y-%m-%d  %T');`

Comment: Thanks, the result format is ok, but still the same warning: `Truncated incorrect datetime value`